# Sorting data in a pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sorting, pivot-table

I have a table of the following structure:

```
Title text
LineNo integer
Key   text
Value text
```

I created a pivot table to convert row data to column name:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Title, [Key],[Value] FROM Table1 WHERE [Key] LIKE 'Field_%' AND [LineNo]>0) as Data 
PIVOT(
MAX([Value])
FOR [Key] IN([Field_1],[Field_2],[Field_3])) As Piv
```

Now how can I order the data By Title and then the Line number?

Comment: Convert the `pivot` into `dynamic pivot` then while generating pivot column list order the columns in required order

Comment: your result has 4 columns, title, Field_1, Field_2, Field_3, right?

Comment: NoDisplayName, turns out creating dynamic pivot query was not necessary - I just added ORDER BY after pivot table alias